# Looking for an easy way to skip undefined variables in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Instead of constantly making an if statement to see if a variable is in the array, I would like a simpler solution. Does anyone know of one?

```
@if(isset($content->title))
    <h2>{{ $content->title }}</h2>
@endif
```

Or

```
{{ (isset($content-title)) ? "<h2>$content->title</h2>" : "" }}
```

Is in my opinion way too much coding. So I am hoping someone knows of a plugin that does something like:

```
{{ @$content->title }}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 13):

Blade has a special `or` keyword for this:

```html
<h2>{{ $content->title or '' }}</h2>
```

Read about it in [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data), under the title **Echoing Data If It Exists**.

---

In newer versions of PHP, you can use the `??` operator for this:

```html
<h2>{{ $content->title ?? '' }}</h2>
```

Comment: What about skipping variable passed to a function? for example: {{ TemplateDynamic::getNumberOfColumns($display) }} if $display is not passed and you don't want to set up default since it's set in a function already.

Comment: @trainoasis - In newer versions of PHP you can do `getNumberOfColumns($display ?? null)`

Comment: Thanks @Joseph didnt know about null coalesce operator, I do now! Exactly what I need often :)